# Draper with Bootstrap Pagination - undefined method 'total_pages'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, decorator, will-paginate, draper

I'm using Draper to decorate my views and move some logic out of them but I'm struggling with this question - how to setup Draper with Bootstrap Pagination (`will_paginate`)?

By default I have this:

```
delegate_all
```

And from Draper documentation I've tried adding this:

```
delegate :current_page, :per_page, :offset, :total_entries, :total_pages
```

But it still returns an error when calling pagination in the view.
My controller defines decoration and pagination like this:

```
@matches = Match.all.paginate(:per_page => 10, :page => params[:page]).decorate
```

And my view:

```
<%= will_paginate @matches, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails %>
```

Update:

```
class ApplicationDecorator < Draper::Decorator
  def self.collection_decorator_class
    PaginatingDecorator
  end
end


class PaginatingDecorator < Draper::Decorator
  # support for will_paginate
  delegate :current_page, :total_entries, :total_pages, :per_page, :offset
end


class PlayerDecorator < ApplicationDecorator
  delegate_all
  decorates_association :matches


class MatchDecorator < ApplicationDecorator
  delegate_all
  decorates_association :players
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://github.com/drapergem/draper/issues/429

```
# app/decorators/application_decorator.rb
class ApplicationDecorator < Draper::Decorator
  def self.collection_decorator_class
    PaginatingDecorator
  end
end

# app/decorators/paginating_decorator.rb
class PaginatingDecorator < Draper::CollectionDecorator
  # support for will_paginate
  delegate :current_page, :total_entries, :total_pages, :per_page, :offset
end

# app/decorators/whatever_decorator.rb
class WhateverDecorator < ApplicationDecorator
end
```

Comment: I'm actually using `all` to order items by date. The full line is: `    @matches = Match.all.order( "date DESC" ).paginate(:per_page => 10, :page => params[:page]).decorate
` 
But I did try without `all` and it didn't change a thing. Still an error.

Comment: Does it mean I have to make a `PaginationDecorator` and add delegation to it?

Comment: Yes, So that you can reuse that PaginationDecorator for pagination on other models.

Comment: Ok, so after adding it all I'm running into this issue: [issue#650](https://github.com/drapergem/draper/issues/650)

Comment: can you please update your code here ? have you verified you are using singular decorators ?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. :) I've updated my answer with the current decorators that are causing `Unknown key: :with. Valid keys are: :context` error.

Comment: please inherit Pagination decorator with  Draper::CollectionDecorator

class PaginatingDecorator < Draper::CollectionDecorator

Comment: Yesss it works! Thank you so much! Please update your answer with the explanation so I can approve it. :))